# Add column values as new row conditionally

Tags: r

I csv data file in below format:

```
1:

101

102

2:

103

104

105

3:

106

107
```

I want result as below in R

```
Value       id
101         1
102         1
103         2
104         2
105         2
106         3
107         3
```

I did using for loop but it takes lot of time. Original data 3MB file.

Added extra column "m_id" in test_data dataframe and executed below code.

```
f <- function(x){
    value = 0
    if(endsWith(as.character(x) ,":") == TRUE){
        value = substr(x,0,nchar(x)-1)
    }
    return (value)
}

for(row in 1:nrow(test_data)){
    id = 0
    id = f(as.character(test_data[row,1]))
    if(id != 0){
        m_id = id
    }
    test_data[row,2]<-m_id
}
```

How i can achieve the above requirement without for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the phantastic `tidyverse` package with some logic:

```
library(tidyverse)
junk = "
1:

101

102

2:

103

104

105

3:

106

107"

df <- data_frame(text=junk)
df %>%
  separate_rows(text, sep = '\n') %>%
  filter(text != "") %>%
  extract(text, into = c('group'), regex = "^(\\d+):", remove = FALSE) %>%
  fill(group) %>%
  filter(!grepl("^\\d+:", text)) %>%
  select(group, text)
```

---

This yields

```
# A tibble: 7 x 2
  group text 
  <chr> <chr>
1 1     101  
2 1     102  
3 2     103  
4 2     104  
5 2     105  
6 3     106  
7 3     107
```

Comment: Thank you Jan i tried on full data set and it is working absolutely fine. Putting different functions together is something i need to work more on.

Comment: @NeerajSharma: Well then, please read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235

Answer (score 0):

Will work as well:

```
df <- read.table(col.names = "x",
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                 text = "1:
101
102
2:
103
104
105
3:
106
107")

retain <- function(x) {
  res <- rep(NA, length(x))
  for (i in seq_along(x)) {
    if (grepl(":", x[i])) {
      res[i] <- x[i]
    } else {
      res[i] <- res[i-1]
    }
  }
  return(res)
} 
df$id <- retain(df$x)
df <- subset(df, id != x)
df$id <- as.numeric(gsub(":", "", df$id))
df
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(id = str_detect(V1, ":"),
         id = case_when(id == TRUE ~ V1)) %>% 
  fill(id) %>% 
  filter(V1 != id) %>% 
  mutate(id = str_extract(id, "^(\\d+)"))
```

> ```
>    V1 id
> 1 101  1
> 2 102  1
> 3 103  2
> 4 104  2
> 5 105  2
> 6 106  3
> 7 107  3
> ```

We could also do:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(id = str_extract(V1, "^(\\d+):"),
         id = str_extract(id, "^(\\d+)")) %>% 
  fill(id) %>% 
  mutate(V1 = str_replace(V1, "^(\\d+):", NA_character_)) %>% 
  drop_na()
```

---

Data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "1:

                 101

                 102

                 2:

                 103

                 104

                 105

                 3:

                 106

                 107", stringsAsFactor = F)
```